# android from jsonparser changing jackson

Tags: android, json, parsing, jackson

I need to change json parser use jackson,
because this app parser data more than originally planned,

tempActivity.java

```
package com.xxx.xxx;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.xxx.xxx.libs.JSONParser;

public class tempActivity extends MainActivity {
    ListView list;
    TextView name;
    TextView intro;
    TextView info;
    tempLazyAdapter adapter;
    String searchStr;

    //Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http:/xxx/json.php?keyword=";
    private static String pageurl = "&page=";
    //private static String encodedurl = "http://www.ebuddha.org/temp_json.php";
    //String url= getResources().getString(R.string.temp_url);
    //JSON Node Names
    String encodedurl = url;
    private static final String TAG_OS = "temp";
    private static Context mContext; 
    JSONArray temp = null;
    JSONArray tmp_temp = null;
    JSONArray newtemp = null;

    private int preLast;
    // Flag for current page
    int current_page = 1;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        mContext = getApplicationContext(); 

        if(bundle.getString("keyword") != null){
            // Getting JSON from URL
            try {
                searchStr = URLEncoder.encode(bundle.getString("keyword"),"UTF-8");
                encodedurl = url + searchStr + pageurl + current_page ;

            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        acttemp = true;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);

        final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            //notify user you are online
            oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            new JSONParse().execute();
        } else {
            //notify user you are not online
            Toast.makeText(tempActivity.this, R.string.disconnect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eText_search);
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    char lastCharacter = s.charAt(s.length() - 1); 

                    if (lastCharacter == '\n') { 
                        String instr = s.subSequence(0, s.length() - 1).toString();
                        try {
                            current_page = 1; 
                            searchStr = URLEncoder.encode(instr,"UTF-8");
                            encodedurl = url + searchStr + pageurl + current_page;
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
                            //notify user you are online
                            oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                            new JSONParse().execute();
                        } else {
                            //notify user you are not online
                            Toast.makeText(tempActivity.this, R.string.disconnect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } 
                        edittext.setText("");
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                } 
            }
        });

        // Implementing scroll refresh
        list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {
               // Log.e("Get position", "--firstItem:" + firstItem + "  visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount + "  totalItems:" + totalItems + "  pageCount:" + pageCount);
                int total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;
                final int lastItem = firstItem + visibleItemCount;

                // Total array list i have so it
                //if (pageCount < 2) {

                    if (total == totalItems) {
                        if(preLast!=lastItem){

                            preLast = lastItem;
                        current_page++;
                        encodedurl = url + searchStr + pageurl + current_page;
                        new JSONParse().execute();

                        }
                    }
                //} else {
                //    Log.e("hide footer", "footer hide");
                //    listView.removeFooterView(footer);
                //}
            }

        });        

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        if(list != null){
            list.setAdapter(null);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.gc(); 
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            intro = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.intro);
            info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(tempActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.load_temp_data));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);  
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();


        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(encodedurl);
            return json;
        }


         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                if(current_page <= 1){
                    temp = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    adapter=new tempLazyAdapter(mContext, tempActivity.this, temp);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
                }else{
                    newtemp = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                     for (int i = 0; i < newtemp.length(); i++) {
                         temp.put(newtemp.get(i));
                        }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

        private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //selectItem(position);
            TextView tid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tid);
            String selectTid = tid.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(tempActivity.this, "click:" + selectTid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent tempInfoIntent = new Intent(tempActivity.this,
                    tempInfoActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("tid", selectTid);
            tempInfoIntent.putExtras(bundle); 
            startActivity(tempInfoIntent);     
        }
    }

    }
}
```

With json I am parsing this as follows :
JSONParser.java

```
package com.xxx.xxx.libs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

//import com.xxx.xxx.ImageLoader;
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            /*
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

because this app need best performance. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Jackson in combination with Retrofit which is build upon RxJava. So you don't have to care about async tasks. The library will do everything for you.